# Customize a variable in the Wordpress customizer and make it change depending on the selected device

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, customization

I want to add a variable of the text size and that this can be modified with different values ​​for each device

```
function themeslug_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    // Do stuff with $wp_customize, the WP_Customize_Manager object.

    $wp_customize->add_panel('accommodation_panel',array(
        'title'=>'Accommodation Texts',
        'description'=> 'This is panel Description',
        'priority'=> 10,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section('section_accommodation',array(
        'title'=>'section',
        'priority'=>10,
        'panel'=>'accommodation_panel',
    ));
    
    
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'font_family_accommodation_setting',
        array(
            'default' => 'Inter',
        )
    );
    
    
    $wp_customize->add_control('font_family_accomoodation',
        array(
            'label'    => __( 'Font Family', 'custom_theme' ),
            'section'  => 'section_accommodation',
            'settings' => 'font_family_accommodation_setting',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'choices'  => array(
                'Open Sans'    => __( 'Open Sans', 'custom_theme' ),
                'Inter'        => __( 'Inter', 'custom_theme' ),
                'Roslindale'  => __( 'Roslindale', 'custom_theme' ),
                'Source Sans Pro' => __( 'Source Sans Pro', 'custom_theme' ),
            )
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_setting('font_size_accommodation_setting',array(
        'default'=>'20',
    ));
    
    
    $wp_customize->add_control('font_size_accomoodation',array(
        'label'=> __( 'Font Size', 'custom_theme' ),
        'type'=>'number',
        'section'=>'section_accommodation',
        'settings'=>'font_size_accommodation_setting',
    ));
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'themeslug_customize_register' );
```

I wanted to know what code is necessary or what needs to be modified so that this text size variable can store various data and how to collect it to apply it to the css